# Add a directory as a target in chocolatey nuspec file

Tags: chocolatey

i want to add a directory as a target in .nuspec file.i tried :

```
<file src="bin\banner\*" target="bin\banner\" />
```

chocolatey didn't elicit any error and created the nupkg file ,but when i download my package from chocolatey and install it,i found that  the files in the sub-directories are missing.

i am not very familiar with chocolatey,so Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
<file src="bin\banner\**\*" target="bin\banner" />
```

The inclusion of the `**` instructs the packaging process to go into each sub-directroy

Comment: thanks it helped alot